# How to deploy branch to remote with git push receive hooks?

Tags: git, deployment

I did deploying via post-receive hooks so far, which worked great as long as I am working on the master branch. Now I want to deploy a feature branch and this somehow does not work and has no effect at all.

The output looks like this:

```
 git push staging 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 371 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://fx/home/git/staging_wg.git
   b9c2dcf..4110f10  feature/WG-173-redesign-detail-page -> feature/WG-173-redesign-detail-page
```

So there seems to be the feature branch deployed. But the code is not there.

cat staging.git/hooks/post-receive

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/www/staging_git checkout -f
find /home/www/staging -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

If I switch back to master branch, I can successfully deploy.

How can it be done to deploy a different branch then master via this simple command?

Comment: Git is not a good deployment tool. But, if you want to proceed anyway, read up on how, even in a bare repository, Git's *index* keeps track of what's in the work-tree. Then note that there's an implied assumption that there's exactly *one* work-tree for the one current branch in the repository.

Comment: Thank you for your help torek. I must admit that I do not really understand what the suggestion is, My question is, how can I push to my remote environment while I am on a different branch then master. What is there, that I need to configure or change within my command.

Comment: Your command says `git checkout -f`. What branch does that check out? (Read the `git checkout` documentation carefully!)